# Get SourceSet full path string or path directory

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, source-sets

I would like to know if there is a property that returns a SourceSet full path string or file directory, something like `${project.projectDir}/src/${sourceSet.name}`.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    foo {
        java {
            srcDir 'example/dir/java'
        }
    }
}

// For example, this could return pathToProject/src/example/dir
println sourceSets.foo.srcDir
```

Comment: `sourceSets.foo.java.getSrcDirs()` returns a collection of source directories for foo.java

Comment: @RaGe That looks like an answer. Also as with all getters you can just use `sourceSets.foo.java.srcDirs`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
productFlavors {
    admin { }
    customer { }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        //other typical sourceSets stuff
    }

    admin.java.srcDirs = ['src/admin']
    customer.java.srcDirs = ['src/customer']
}
```